# Google Adwords API authentication issue

Tags: python, google-ads-api

Just getting started on the Adwords API, for some reason I can't seem to connect at all.

The code below, straight from the tutorial throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    client = AdWordsClient(path=os.path.join('Users', 'ravinthambapillai', 'Google Drive', 'client_secrets.json'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adspygoogle/adwords/AdWordsClient.py", line 151, in __init__
    self._headers = self.__LoadAuthCredentials()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adspygoogle/adwords/AdWordsClient.py", line 223, in __LoadAuthCredentials
    return super(AdWordsClient, self)._LoadAuthCredentials()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adspygoogle/common/Client.py", line 94, in _LoadAuthCredentials
    raise ValidationError(msg)
**ValidationError: Authentication data is missing.**

from adspygoogle.adwords.AdWordsClient import AdWordsClient
from adspygoogle.common import Utils
client = AdWordsClient(path=os.path.join('Users', 'this-user', 'this-folder', 'client_secrets.json'))
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's two issues. First, try removing the last path element, as far as I recall, the `path` parameter expects a directory that contains the authentication pickle, logs etc. This approach requires that you already have a valid `auth_token.pkl`.

Second, it appears that you're using OAuth2 for authentication (I'm guessing by the `client_secrets.json` file). For this to work, you'll need to use the `oauth2client` library and provide an oauth2credentials instance in the `headers` parameter to `AdWordsClient`.

The following is straight from the file `examples/adspygoogle/adwords/v201302/misc/use_oauth2.py` in the client distribution and should give you an idea how it works:

```
# We're using the oauth2client library:
# http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/list
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
  client_id=oauth2_client_id,
  client_secret=oauth2_client_secret,
  # Scope is the server address with '/api/adwords' appended.
  scope='https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords',
  user_agent='oauth2 code example')

# Get the authorization URL to direct the user to.
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

print ('Log in to your AdWords account and open the following URL: \n%s\n' %
     authorize_url)
print 'After approving the token enter the verification code (if specified).'
code = raw_input('Code: ').strip()

credential = None
try:
credential = flow.step2_exchange(code)
except FlowExchangeError, e:
sys.exit('Authentication has failed: %s' % e)

# Create the AdWordsUser and set the OAuth2 credentials.
client = AdWordsClient(headers={
  'developerToken': '%s++USD' % email,
  'clientCustomerId': client_customer_id,
  'userAgent': 'OAuth2 Example',
  'oauth2credentials': credential
})
```

Comment: dorian: here the client_customer_id is a variable.  Is this value supposed to be provided by the customer, or is it considered a confidential value?

Comment: 'client_customer_id' is just the ID of the Google AdWords account that you want to access ("123-456-7890"). AFAIR it's possible to omit this parameter, in which case you'll access the top-level Adwords account connected to your Google account.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the `AdWordsClient` api but are you sure your path is correct?

your current `join` produces a relative path, do you need an absolute one?

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('Users', 'this-user')
'Users/this-user'
```

For testing you could hardcode the absoulte path in to make sure it is not a path issue

I would also make sure that `'client_secrets.json` exists, and that it is readable by the user executing python